# How to set minimum required iOS version to 5.0.1

Tags: iphone, ios

My app needs to support iOS version >= 5.0.1. I can't support <= 5.0 because I need to set the "Don't BackUp" flag for the data downloaded!

How do I set the minimum iOS version required to 5.0.1?

Answer (score 3):

That flag was introduced in iOS 5.1, so you'll have to change your deployment target to 5.1 to be able to do that.

Comment: In http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1719/_index.html. that flag may be set for ios 5.0.1. So i want my app supports from ios 5.0.1 and later ?

Comment: @SevenNguyen Use `NSURLIsExcludedFromBackupKey` on iOS 5.1, the extended attribute for iOS 5.0.1 and put the data in the Caches directory for iOS 5.0 and then set the deployment target to iOS 5.0 (but please handle OS upgrades gracefully)

Comment: @JustSid thank you for answer.I still want to ask.in my app i download the data and place to app's documment. The data is a folder and in folder have many file. i want to ask when i set 'Don't BackUp flag' i just set for app's documment or set for all file in forder data? please help me i don't want my app  to be rejected again.

Comment: @SevenNguyen Sorry, I don't know if the flag is inherited, but I would say no. Set it for all files and you should be good to go.

Answer (score -1):

Use it:

- Double-click on your Target's name in Xcode to bring up the Target Info.
- Go to the Build/Summary tab and search for "iPhone OS Deployment Target".
- Pick whichever SDK you want to use as your minimum requirements.

One thing is that it won't tell you if it doesn't work on a certain version. You'll have to compare your methods with which ones are available in each version manually.

You can help curb this by changing your Base SDK too:

- Same place, search for "Base SDK".
- Change it to the lowest iPhone OS Device SDK you can/want.
  (On Snow Leopard, this is 2.2.1; Leopard can go as low as 2.0 if you installed it with Xcode.)